# In need of a C++ function that breaks a line into strings that include only numbers/letters

Tags: c++, string, line, break

I would like to know how it's possible to break a line into strings that include numbers and letters only (no punctuation). I've seen formulas online that do that, but omit instructions on how to omit punctuation.

Comment: Can you provide examples of line(s) that you are referring in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions from `<cctype>` to test your characters.  In your case, you probably want to use [`isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum).

Comment: Is it possible to do this if I treat my words as type string, or can I only do this with char *?

Comment: When you use `string::operator[]` you get a char out, just as if you were using a `char*`.  The short answer is "yes".

Comment: @Michformer `std::isalnum` will only work on individual characters so both options are viable.

Comment: Also, it needs to be a function that processes (i.e. returns) one word at a time

Comment: When I extract a character from the string, can I place it inside an array or something (char * extract[])?

Comment: @Michformer Just append it to another `string`.

Comment: void break_line (string line){

            char str[] = line;
            int i;
            char ext [];


             for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
                if (isalnum(str[i] || '-' == str[i])){
                     str[i] = ext[i]

Damn how do you indent that code in a comment? I keep making 4 spaces before each line and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

This is where the erase-remove idiom comes in handy. Edit: lambda unnecessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "!%@T%abc";
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ispunct), s.end());
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The details vary according to what, exactly, you want to achieve but let us assume that there is a set of characters you want and all others are unwanted, and the output will be all the contiguous groups of wanted characters in the input. Then the pseudocode would be:

```
while input not empty
    remove all unwanted characters from from of input string
    find first unwanted character in input string
    if not found
        last output string is remains of input string
        empty out input string
    else
        next output string is all chars before unwanted char
        remove all the wanted chars we found from the input string
    end
```

sorry for the pseudocode but thats the best I can do without knowing what string class you are using.

Comment: I'm using type string.

Comment: I should have assumed that. I'm more familiar with MFC CString, which is increasingly a pain for me. Well, for example, you can use find_first_not_of to find the first character that is not in a 'wanted' list, erase to remove characters from the string and so forth...